# Using rsync to remote SSH user with no shell access

Tags: apache, ssh, apache2, rsync, jenkins

I set up Jenkins CI to deploy my PHP app to our QA Apache server and I ran into an issuse. I successfully set up the pubkey authentication from the local jenkins account to the remote apache account, but when I use `rsync`, I get the following error:

```
[jenkins@build ~]# rsync -avz -e ssh test.txt apache@site.example.com:/path/to/site
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(64) [sender=2.6.8]
[jenkins@build ~]#
```

One potential problem is that the remote `apache` account doesn't have a valid shell account, should I create a remote account with shell access and part of the `"apache"` group? It is not an SSH key problem, since `ssh apache@site.example.com` connects successfully, but quickly kicks me out since `apache` doesn't have a shell.

Comment: I know this is pretty old thread, but if somebody comes across this page in future...
Even though I had valid account, I had the same error message showing up, but got that fixed when I fixed my .bashrc . I removed the statement "echo setting DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" which was there before in my .bashrc. rsync has issues with that statement for some reason. So, fixing .bashrc/.cshrc/.profile helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would probably be the easiest thing to do. You will probably want to only set it up with a limited shell like [rssh](http://pizzashack.org/rssh/) or [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly) to only allow file transfers.  You may also want to set up a chroot jail so that it can't see your whole filesystem.

Comment: can you provide the command ?. I installed rssh and tried :rsync --partial --progress --rsh=rssh user@host:/path/remote_file local_file  ;still getting the same problem. May be I got it wrong. -Thanks

Comment: To be up-to-date, rssh is deprecated since a while. It's better to use [/usr/sbin/rush](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/rush/), that can manage precise rules for rights.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461837/auto-mounting-of-remote-folder-with-sshfs-without-giving-shell-access also.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that that would probably be the easiest thing to do.  We do something similar, but use `scp` instead.  Something like:

```
scp /path/to/test.txt apache@site.example.com:/path/to/site
```